# Spock returns empty list when mocking JdbcTemplate

Tags: unit-testing, spock

I have a service class that uses a JdbcTemplate to perform a search using product ids and returns the matched products.

Here is the class

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
```

@Service
public class ProductService {

```
private final QueryBuilderUtility queryBuilderUtility;

private final JdbcTemplate productJdbcTemplate;

public ProductService(@Qualifier("productJdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate productJdbcTemplate, QueryBuilderUtility queryBuilderUtility) {
    this.productJdbcTemplate = productJdbcTemplate;
    this.queryBuilderUtility = queryBuilderUtility;
}


public List<Product> findProducts(List<Long> productCodes) {
    String productQuery = queryBuilderUtility.buildSelectQuery(productCodes);
    List<Product> products = productJdbcTemplate.query( productQuery, new ProductRowMapper(), productCodes.toArray());
    return products;
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
 class ProductServiceSpec extends Specification { 
 
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mock()
QueryBuilderUtility queryBuilderUtility = Mock()
ProductService productService
List<Long> productCodes =  [33334L, 66754L, 56772L]
TestUtil testUtil = new TestUtil();
List<Product> products = testUtil.createProducts()

def setup(){
    productService = new ProductService( jdbcTemplate, queryBuilderUtility)
}

def 'Find Products for product codes'(){

    given:

    1 *  jdbcTemplate.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Object []) >> products

    when:
    //1 *  jdbcTemplate.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Long []) >> products
    assert products.size() == 3



    List<Product> result = productService.findProducts(productCodes)
    println "Result is ${result}" // empty list
    then:
    1 == 1
}
```

}

I tried using a stub for the jdbcTemplate to return a list of Products like so, but the list is empty

```
  List<Product> products = ...   
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Stub()
  jdbcTemplate.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Long []) >> products
```

However, when I debug, it returns a product list with size 0, even though there are 3 elements in the product list. Is this expected?  If so does that mean it is not possible to mock or stub the JdbcTemplate in Spock? I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.

I tried this as well and it did not work;

```
JdbcTemplate template = Mock()
1 * template.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Object[]) >> products
```

and

```
1 * template.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Long[]) >> products
```

Comment: Try turning it into a mock and use `then: 1 * jdbcTemplate.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Long []) >> products` it should tell you why it doesn't match.

Comment: I had done that already but it did not work. That's when I tried using a. stub. in the case of a mock, it does not even match and returns null

Comment: JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mock()
        1 *  jdbcTemplate.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Long []) >> products returns null

Comment: And you don't get an insufficient invocations exception? Maybe share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with us, or at least your test class.

Comment: I cannot add the QueryBuilderUtility or the connection class details.  However, the rest is the code copied.

Comment: I have tried putting the jdbcTemplate mock invocation in various places in the block but that does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `QueryBuilderUtility` as a mock:

```java
QueryBuilderUtility queryBuilderUtility = Mock()
```

I.e., every method call returns `null`. So you either need to use a real query builder utility instead of a mock or make sure to stub the method result, e.g.

```java
def 'Find Products for product codes'() {
  given:
  1 * jdbcTemplate.query(_ as String, _ as ProductRowMapper, _ as Object[]) >> products
  queryBuilderUtility.buildSelectQuery(_) >> "my query"

  expect:
  productService.findProducts(productCodes).size() == 3
}
```

Now the test should pass.

By the way: In this simple case where you do not seem need any value constraints for the method parameters of `jdbcTemplate.query` but `_` for each, you could also simply write:

```java
  1 * jdbcTemplate.query(*_) >> products
```

---

**Update:** See my full example project with several dummy classes I created in order to make your example code work:

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&gist=d9a7384f131134b0a810b48636af1736).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out. I had actually used a query string as well but it did not work. I put the queryBuilderUtility generated string before the jdbcTemplate invocation which is different from what you did, does that matter? Also, I used the fake query string as the first argument of the jdbcTemplate call, but no luck.

Comment: I updated my answer, copying all my dummy classes into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which you can conveniently execute in the Try it in the Groovy Web Console and compare with your own code. Without you sharing a full reproducer, I cannot help you any further. It was a lot of work to try and recreate your situation locally already, in order to be able to verify the correctness of my solution. Actually, it would be your job as the person asking the question to provide an MCVE. Please do so next time.

Comment: Thanks a lot kriegaex, I really appreciate this. It now works, brilliant!

Comment: Yes, I will. Really appreciated!